# porting ostream::opfx / osfx from Unix to Linux

Tags: c++, unix, porting, iostream, redhat

I am porting some C++ code from Unix to Linux (Red Hat).

I have run into the following pattern:

```
ostream& myfunction(ostream& os)
{
  if (os.opfx())
  {
    os << mydata;
    os.osfx();
  }
  return os;
}
```

The functions `opfx` and `osfx` are not available under Red Hat 4.5.  I saw a suggestion [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2001-02/msg00334.html) to use the `ostream::sentry` functionality:

```
ostream& myfunction_ported(ostream& os)
{
  ostream::sentry ok(os);
  if (ok)
  {
    os << mydata;
  }
  return os;
}
```

I see from [here](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/comp/unix/gnu-info/iostream_3.html) that the purpose of `opfx` is to verify the stream state before flushing it and continuing.

My questions:

I thought the `ostream` functions already checked the stream state before operating on the stream.  Is this true?  Was this not true at some point?

Is replacing `opfx` with `sentry` necessary?  What does `sentry` give me that `operator<<` doesn't give me already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any existing inserter (unless it's really horribly buggy) is already doing to create a sentry object, so as long as your do your work via an existing inserter, you don't need to create a sentry object yourself.

You *do* need to create a sentry object when you write your data directly to the stream buffer on your own, without help from any existing inserter (i.e., when you're not using anything else that'll create a sentry for you).

For this code, you can just eliminate creating the sentry objects completely and do something like:

```
ostream& myfunction(ostream& os)
{
    return os << mydata;
}
```

Note that the existing code was declared to return an `ostream &`, but didn't seem to actually return anything.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation.  I missed the return statement when I typed in the two samples, and have fixed it.